# Rhino-etl/C# Data Mapping issue

Tags: c#, sql, rhino-etl

I'm trying to retrieve data from one database and insert it into another, I am using Rhino-etl to carry out the data mapping, within a C# application. The destination database is located on a server, the source database is on my local machine. Every time I run the program it returns the following error...

"Failed to execute operation..."
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

This issue is obviously related to a date field.

If I run this code from another machine, I don't encounter this problem. I've checked the language of my local and database server (and the databases), I have had a look at the regional settings, I've even converted the date field values to "dd-MMM-yyyy" before they're inserted into the destination database. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if you're using a SqlBulkInsert or a SqlBatchOperation operation to write to the database.  Could you specify, or better yet, add the code in whatever operation you're using to this question?